# constrained bayesian linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression, bayesian

I am trying to carry out bayesian linear regression subject to linear inequality constraints on the coefficients. I have no idea how to add constraints in a bayesian framework.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Muhammad Asif Rana,

I suggest using **bnlearn package in R**. It support data with linear relations, i tried the package with generated linear Gaussian distribution and it estimated the coefficients perfectly (it can also estimate uniform distribution). Moreover, you can add **constraint** by first modelling the DAG of the Bayesian network and score it **OR** you can use attached **penalizing function** from the same package (check the package book for penalizing details).